# Python/Panda : how to generate two dimensional records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has records like :

```
year    month   day min-temp    max-temp    precipitation   snow    snow-cover
2018    7   30  77  51  0.0 0.0 0.0
2018    7   29  75  52  0.04    0.0 0.0
2018    7   28  77  56  0.01    0.0 0.0
2018    7   27  80  56  0.35    0.0 0.0
```

I have records for about 150 years like that.However, if some data is missing in some column, then that column's value is empty. Additionally, records are not avaiable for all days for every year.

I have create a data structure or a dataframe ( so that I can plot in graph later ) that should have rows that are months of the year and columns are [min-temp, max-temp, precipitation,snow,snow-cover] based on 25 years.

My dataframe/data structure value should look like (example):

[image]

Any column can have missing data if there is no record found for that month for 25 years. In case of missing data, the entry will hold "" value.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `groupby` with `agg`

```
d={'min-temp':'min','max-temp':'max','precipitation':'sum','snow':'sum','snow-cover':'sum'}
df.groupby(['year','month']).agg(d)
Out[220]: 
            precipitation  snow-cover  max-temp  snow  min-temp
year month                                                     
2018 7                0.4         0.0        56   0.0        75
```